# How to subscribe the address logs in solana by using python?

Tags: python, subscription

I want to subscribe the logs of my address in solana by using python

Answer (score 2):

Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here. This is a sample code to subscribe to logs for the token program:

```
Python - 3.9.13
Solana - 0.29.1
base58 - 2.1.1
asyncio - 3.4.3
asyncstdlib - 3.10.5

import solana
import asyncio
from asyncstdlib import enumerate
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solders.rpc.config import RpcTransactionLogsFilterMentions
wss_url = ""

async def main():
    async with connect(wss_url) as websocket:
        await websocket.logs_subscribe(RpcTransactionLogsFilterMentions(Pubkey.from_string("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")),commitment="finalized")
        print("started")
        first_resp = await websocket.recv()
        subscription_id = first_resp[0].result
        async for idx, msg in enumerate(websocket):
            if idx == 10:
                break
            print(msg)
        await websocket.logs_unsubscribe(subscription_id)
await main()
```

You need to fill in your wss endpoint in the code. If you need one, feel free to try out our services. Our developer plan is free and it gives 3 Million free requests.